# Why have 2 controllers with the same name in my API Yii 2?

Tags: php, api, yii

In the Yii Framework documentation I was reading about the versioning of the API and I came across this structure of the image, I could not understand very well, what is the difference between the controller that is in the common/controllers folder for the modules/v1/controllers folder? The same goes for models, because a model is created in the commons folder and then created the same model in the modules/v1/models folder? If anyone can explain me, thank you.

I know it's important to keep the old version of the API, I just wanted to understand what each controller has, if someone extends it from any specific class, I got a little lost with respect to the structure.

[image]

Comment: what if you want to make a base `UserController` with common actions 
 like `delete` overriding `checkAccess()`, `behaviors()`  and extend your controllers in the modules `v1` and add rest of the function in the version-specific controllers, and so on with the `v2` to add new methods and upgrades

Comment: Thank you my friend